# spring r2dbc with custom aop is not working

Tags: spring-aop, spring-data-r2dbc

I am using spring aop and r2dbc.

By the way, if you use @transactional and the aop I made, only transactional is applied.

When spring aop and jpa were used, when additional aop was applied by attaching @transactional and @Logging annotations to one method, transactional was performed first, and then aop applied to logging annotation worked.

By the way, when using spring aop and r2dbc, only @Transactional is applied, and the aop I applied is not working.

If I give an order to aop, the custom advisor will work first, so why does it work normally, but if i don't give an order doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With all due respect, nobody here has a magical crystal globe, can read your mind or debug prose. Thank you.